# How to intergate a Django app into a Wagtail CMS

Tags: django, wagtail

I have a small django app with some CBV's (f.i. a HTMX/ListView)
I want to integrate this app in an exciting Wagtail site:
So it is part of Wagtail pages, the menu structure and I can make use of Streamfields on those Django app pages.
How can I achieve this?

Looking for an example. Lot of examples how to integrate Wagtail into a Django app, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

I have set-up an application using django models (instead of wagtail's Page class).  Originally I used views to update the model, in the manner described in your question but I found this unsatisfactory and as it is a small application (4 tables) I integrated it into wagtail.  I did it a awhile ago, but I'm pretty sure this is all I needed to do.

In the django application, define the models as usual, but add panel definitions for use in wagtail admin.  e.g.

== models.py ==

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False, null=True,)
    format = models.IntegerField(blank=False, )
    start_date = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False,)
.
. etc.
.

    panels = [
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldPanel('name'),
            FieldPanel('format'),
            FieldPanel('start_date'),
 
.etc.
.
.
        ]
```

Create a wagtail_hooks.py in your application, you'll need to import ModelAdmin, modeladmin_register, ModelAdminGroup from wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.options and then for each of your models create a class like so (again I'll use the model Event for the example)

== wagtail_hooks.py ==

```
class EventAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = Event
    menu_label = 'Events' 
    menu_icon = 'radio-full'  # change as required
    list_display = ('name',
                    'start_date',
                    )
    search_fields = ('start_date', 'name')
```

I set my application (called "competition") as a main menu item, with sub menu items for each model, at the foot of wagtail_hooks.py

```
class CompetitionGroup(ModelAdminGroup):
    menu_label = 'Competitions'
    menu_icon = 'radio-empty'
    menu_order = 200
    items = (CompconfigAdmin, EventAdmin, VenueAdmin, EventVenueAdmin, RoundAdmin)


modeladmin_register(CompetitionGroup)
```

Note: menu_order, starts at 000, 100 being the 2nd item, 200 the 3rd an so on.

Don't forget to add your application to settings.py

Credit to learnwagtail.com for their tutorial that explains how to do this and I'm pretty sure there's info in wagtail docs about this too.
If I've missed something just shout I'll do my best to help out.

Since writing the above, I found the page you need in the docs: [ModelAdmin](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/reference/contrib/modeladmin/index.html), hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I realize I'm quite late, and I'm usually reluctant to push my own projects as solutions. However, as the creator of [wagtail-app-pages](https://wagtail-app-pages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), I think that might be exactly what you're looking for.
I ran into similar issues, wanting to package a set of CBVs into easily reusable wagtail pages, and I'm quite happy with the results.